# How to know if the method is Public, Protected or Private in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, access-modifiers

Here are three methods `function_one`, `function_two` and `function_three` in `Example` class.

```
class Example
{
    private function function_one() { ... }

    protected function function_two() { ... }

    public function function_three() { ... }

    public function check_here()
    {
        if (is_public_method('function_three')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to know which Access Modifier (`public`, `protected`, `private`) is the method. The imaginary `is_public_method` should return true because `function_three` is `public` method. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/reflectionclass) and [`ReflectionMethod`](http://php.net/reflectionmethod):

```
public function check_here()
{
    $obj = new ReflectionClass($this);
    return $obj->getMethod('function_three')->isPublic();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be looking at [ReflectionMethod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.construct.php)'s [isPublic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.ispublic.php) method.